# Group By & Having vs. SubQuery (Where Count is Greater Than 1)

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm struggling here trying to write a script that finds where an order was returned multiple times by the same associate (count greater than 1).  I'm guessing my syntax with the subquery is incorrect.  When I run the script, I get a message back that the "SELECT failed..  [3669] More than one value was returned by the subquery."

I'm not tied to the subquery, and have tried using just the group by and having statements, but I get an error regarding a non-aggregate value.  What's the best way to proceed here and how do I fix this?

Thank you in advance - code below:

```
SEL         s.saletran                                                          
            , s.saletran_dt SALE_DATE
            , r.saletran_id RET_TRAN
            , r.saletran_dt RET_DATE
            , ra.user_id RET_ASSOC
FROM        salestrans s

JOIN        salestrans_refund   r
            ON      r.orig_saletran_id = s.saletran_id
            AND r.orig_saletran_dt = s.saletran_dt
            AND r.orig_loc_id = s.loc_id
            AND r.saletran_dt between s.saletran_dt and s.saletran_dt + 30

JOIN        saletran rt     
            ON          rt.saletran_id = r.saletran_id
            AND     rt.saletran_dt = r.saletran_dt
            AND     rt.loc_id = r.loc_id

JOIN        assoc ra                    --Return Associate
            ON          ra.assoc_prty_id = rt.sls_assoc_prty_id

WHERE  
            (SELECT count(*)
            FROM            saletran_refund
            GROUP BY  ORIG_SLTRN_ID
            ) > 1

            AND     s.saletran_dt between '2015-01-01' and current_date - 1
```

Comment: sorry, there's a couple of typos with the table names...everything's joined appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've got so far, I think you want to use this instead:

```
where r.ORIG_SLTRN_ID in
(select 
ORIG_SLTRN_ID
from
saletran_refund
group by ORIG_SLTRN_ID
having count (*) > 1)
```

That will give you the ORIG_SLTRN_IDs that have more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

you don't give enough for a full answer but this is a start

```
group by s.saletran                                                          
            , s.saletran_dt SALE_DATE
            , r.saletran_id RET_TRAN
            , r.saletran_dt RET_DATE
            , ra.user_id RET_ASSOC 
having count(distinct(ORIG_SLTRN_ID)) > 0
```

this does return more the an one row
run it

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM saletran_refund
GROUP BY  ORIG_SLTRN_ID
```